# Android Studio cannot run AVD after I disabled Hyper-V. How can I re-enable?

Tags: windows-10, android, hyper-v, android-studio, intel-haxm

I disabled Hyper-V by running these commands on my Windows 10 machine as administrator:

`bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off`

`reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\DeviceGuard\Scenarios\HypervisorEnforcedCodeIntegrity" /v "Enabled" /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f`

And I'll be honest I blindly copied them in, I didn't understand them.

Now when I try and run an Android emulator, I get a popup saying "Intel HAXM is required to run this AVD.  HAXM is not installed".

Android Studio and all emulators worked fine before I disabled Hyper-V, and I disabled Hyper-V for reasons unrelated to Android Studio.  I would just like to "revert" the commands I did or re-enable Hyper-V.

Comment: Have you tried to just re-installed HAXM? May be the installer fixes your problems (assuming your system has an Intel CPU).

Comment: @Robert When I follow the prompts I get `Android SDK is up to date.
Running Intel® HAXM installer
Unable to run Intel® HAXM installer: Cannot start process, the working directory 'D:\android\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager' does not exist
Done
`

Comment: Seems you have modified the Andorid SDK without using the SDK manager. Don't do that. Uninstall "Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution" via Windows app list. Open Android SDK manager, uninstall/uncheck HAXM, apply and then re-install it.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following in the command prompt:

```
> bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto
```

Then, restart your computer. This should do the trick to re-enable Hyper-V.